# Get combinations of array without self repetition

Tags: python, numpy, combinations, python-itertools

I have the following array `points` of shape `(3,3)` which are 3D points

```py
[[-0.20592405  0.33034652  1.0430001 ]
 [-0.23757319  0.29612657  1.03800011]
 [-0.304515    0.34571081  1.20400012]]
```

I need to find all the combinations of these three points. I'm doing the following:

```py
comb = np.array(list(itertools.product(points.tolist(), repeat=3)))
```

And I get

```
[[[-0.20592405  0.33034652  1.0430001 ]
  [-0.20592405  0.33034652  1.0430001 ]
  [-0.20592405  0.33034652  1.0430001 ]]

 [[-0.20592405  0.33034652  1.0430001 ]
  [-0.20592405  0.33034652  1.0430001 ]
  [-0.23757319  0.29612657  1.03800011]]

 [[-0.20592405  0.33034652  1.0430001 ]
  [-0.20592405  0.33034652  1.0430001 ]
  [-0.304515    0.34571081  1.20400012]]

 [[-0.20592405  0.33034652  1.0430001 ]
  [-0.23757319  0.29612657  1.03800011]
  [-0.20592405  0.33034652  1.0430001 ]]

 [[-0.20592405  0.33034652  1.0430001 ]
  [-0.23757319  0.29612657  1.03800011]
  [-0.23757319  0.29612657  1.03800011]]

 [[-0.20592405  0.33034652  1.0430001 ]
  [-0.23757319  0.29612657  1.03800011]
  [-0.304515    0.34571081  1.20400012]]

 [[-0.20592405  0.33034652  1.0430001 ]
  [-0.304515    0.34571081  1.20400012]
  [-0.20592405  0.33034652  1.0430001 ]]

 [[-0.20592405  0.33034652  1.0430001 ]
  [-0.304515    0.34571081  1.20400012]
  [-0.23757319  0.29612657  1.03800011]]

 [[-0.20592405  0.33034652  1.0430001 ]
  [-0.304515    0.34571081  1.20400012]
  [-0.304515    0.34571081  1.20400012]]

 [[-0.23757319  0.29612657  1.03800011]
  [-0.20592405  0.33034652  1.0430001 ]
  [-0.20592405  0.33034652  1.0430001 ]]

 [[-0.23757319  0.29612657  1.03800011]
  [-0.20592405  0.33034652  1.0430001 ]
  [-0.23757319  0.29612657  1.03800011]]

 [[-0.23757319  0.29612657  1.03800011]
  [-0.20592405  0.33034652  1.0430001 ]
  [-0.304515    0.34571081  1.20400012]]

 [[-0.23757319  0.29612657  1.03800011]
  [-0.23757319  0.29612657  1.03800011]
  [-0.20592405  0.33034652  1.0430001 ]]

 [[-0.23757319  0.29612657  1.03800011]
  [-0.23757319  0.29612657  1.03800011]
  [-0.23757319  0.29612657  1.03800011]]

 [[-0.23757319  0.29612657  1.03800011]
  [-0.23757319  0.29612657  1.03800011]
  [-0.304515    0.34571081  1.20400012]]

 [[-0.23757319  0.29612657  1.03800011]
  [-0.304515    0.34571081  1.20400012]
  [-0.20592405  0.33034652  1.0430001 ]]

 [[-0.23757319  0.29612657  1.03800011]
  [-0.304515    0.34571081  1.20400012]
  [-0.23757319  0.29612657  1.03800011]]

 [[-0.23757319  0.29612657  1.03800011]
  [-0.304515    0.34571081  1.20400012]
  [-0.304515    0.34571081  1.20400012]]

 [[-0.304515    0.34571081  1.20400012]
  [-0.20592405  0.33034652  1.0430001 ]
  [-0.20592405  0.33034652  1.0430001 ]]

 [[-0.304515    0.34571081  1.20400012]
  [-0.20592405  0.33034652  1.0430001 ]
  [-0.23757319  0.29612657  1.03800011]]

 [[-0.304515    0.34571081  1.20400012]
  [-0.20592405  0.33034652  1.0430001 ]
  [-0.304515    0.34571081  1.20400012]]

 [[-0.304515    0.34571081  1.20400012]
  [-0.23757319  0.29612657  1.03800011]
  [-0.20592405  0.33034652  1.0430001 ]]

 [[-0.304515    0.34571081  1.20400012]
  [-0.23757319  0.29612657  1.03800011]
  [-0.23757319  0.29612657  1.03800011]]

 [[-0.304515    0.34571081  1.20400012]
  [-0.23757319  0.29612657  1.03800011]
  [-0.304515    0.34571081  1.20400012]]

 [[-0.304515    0.34571081  1.20400012]
  [-0.304515    0.34571081  1.20400012]
  [-0.20592405  0.33034652  1.0430001 ]]

 [[-0.304515    0.34571081  1.20400012]
  [-0.304515    0.34571081  1.20400012]
  [-0.23757319  0.29612657  1.03800011]]

 [[-0.304515    0.34571081  1.20400012]
  [-0.304515    0.34571081  1.20400012]
  [-0.304515    0.34571081  1.20400012]]]
```

Which gives me all the combinations, but I want to discard combinations that are repeated. So, let's say for 3D points `a`, `b`, `c` the combinations I'm getting `[[a, a, a], [a, a, b],..,[a, b, c],.., [c, c, c]]`. I want to keep only combinations having all different points i.e. `[a, b, c]`, `[b, c, a]` etc.

Comment: use `combinations` instead of `product`?

Comment: permutations should do: `np.array(list(itertools.permutations(points, r=3)))`

Comment: @QuangHoang you are right, that worked! If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @MustafaAydın I'm trying to avoid repeated points which means the order is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

With `itertools.combinations`, there's only one:

```
l1=[[-0.20592405,  0.33034652,  1.0430001 ],
    [-0.23757319,  0.29612657,  1.03800011],
    [-0.304515,    0.34571081,  1.20400012]]
comb = np.array(list(itertools.combinations(l1, 3)))
#array([[[-0.20592405,  0.33034652,  1.0430001 ],
#        [-0.23757319,  0.29612657,  1.03800011],
#        [-0.304515  ,  0.34571081,  1.20400012]]])
```

With `itertools.permutations`:

```
comb = np.array(list(itertools.permutations(l1, 3)))
```

Value of `comb`:

```
array([[[-0.20592405,  0.33034652,  1.0430001 ],
        [-0.23757319,  0.29612657,  1.03800011],
        [-0.304515  ,  0.34571081,  1.20400012]],

       [[-0.20592405,  0.33034652,  1.0430001 ],
        [-0.304515  ,  0.34571081,  1.20400012],
        [-0.23757319,  0.29612657,  1.03800011]],

       [[-0.23757319,  0.29612657,  1.03800011],
        [-0.20592405,  0.33034652,  1.0430001 ],
        [-0.304515  ,  0.34571081,  1.20400012]],

       [[-0.23757319,  0.29612657,  1.03800011],
        [-0.304515  ,  0.34571081,  1.20400012],
        [-0.20592405,  0.33034652,  1.0430001 ]],

       [[-0.304515  ,  0.34571081,  1.20400012],
        [-0.20592405,  0.33034652,  1.0430001 ],
        [-0.23757319,  0.29612657,  1.03800011]],

       [[-0.304515  ,  0.34571081,  1.20400012],
        [-0.23757319,  0.29612657,  1.03800011],
        [-0.20592405,  0.33034652,  1.0430001 ]]])
```